# using a string or key-val pair as a method argument

Tags: ruby, arguments, key-value

Is there a better way to write this? basically I want to add an argument to a hash. if the argument is a key-val pair, then id like to add it as is. if the argument is a string i'd like to add it as a key with a nil value. the below code works, but is there a more appropriate (simple) way?

2nd question, does calling an each method on an array with two arguments |key, val| automatically convert an array to a hash as it appears to?

```ruby
@some_hash = {}

def some_method(input)
    if input.is_a? Hash
        input.each {|key, val| @some_hash[key] = val}
    else
        input.split(" ").each {|key, val| @some_hash[key] = val}
    end
end

some_method("key" => "val")
```

Comment: In case if string, what would be the sample input ? I don't understand what are you doing `input.split(" ").each {|key, val| @some_hash[key] = val}` here ?

Comment: if input is a string, then the split method converts it to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the result as instructed in the question, but it works differently from the code OP gave (which means that the OP's code does not work as it says):

```
@some_hash = {}

def some_method(input)
  case input
  when Hash then @some_hash.merge!(input)
  when String then @some_hash[input] = nil
  end
end

some_method("foo" => "bar")
some_method("baz")
@some_hash # => {"foo" => "bar", "baz" => nil}
```

- Second question

An array is never automatically converted to a hash. What you are probably mentioning is the fact that the elements of an array within an array `[[:foo, :bar]]` can be referred to separately in:

```
[[:foo, :bar]].each{|f, b| puts f; puts b}
# => foo
# => bar
```

That is due to destructive assignment. When necessary, Ruby takes out the elements of an array as separate things and tries to adjust the number of variables. It is the same as:

```
f, b = [:foo, :bar]
f # => :foo
b # => :bar
```

Here, you don't get `f # => [:foo, :bar]` and `b # => nil`.

Comment: but it seems to give the same result?